# Regex.IsMatch returns true when shouldn't

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a Regex pattern which should allow all alphanumeric characters, and `-`, `_`, `.` and space

`"[A-Za-z0-9-_. ]+"`

I am trying to validate a string against this regex using `Regex.IsMatch`, but it returns `true`. Why?

```
string pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9-_. ]+";
string input = "rtgfd&**((&";
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
// isMatch is true, why?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It matches because your string does contain one or more characters in the `[A-Za-z0-9-_. ]` set. If you want *only* that, change your pattern to this:

```
string pattern = "^[A-Za-z0-9-_. ]+$";
```

It will force the pattern to match from the beginning to the end of the string.

Comment: `.` is special. You need to escape it. `@"^[A-Za-z0-9-_\. ]+$"`

Comment: @wdosanjos No, not in a character class. `Regex.IsMatch("Text", "[.]") // false`

Comment: @wdosanjos Inside a Character class `[]` you dont need to escape.